# Need to build complex SQLite query

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

Have two SQLite tables:

```
sh_item
id
title
..
```

and

```
sh_paramvalues
id
paramid
itemid
value
```

Have some query that I need to modify

```
//$get[0] - search query from user
$this->q = "SELECT * 
              FROM sh_item 
             WHERE title LIKE '%".$get[0]."%' 
                OR descr LIKE '%".$get[0]."%' 
             LIMIT '".$this->page->start."','".$this->page->on1page."'";
```

I need some query that could get value ( LIKE '%".$get[0]."%') from sh_paramvalues where paramid='some my value' and itemid = id which use sh_item in base query.

Maybe I need to use join but I am not good at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//$get[0] - search query from user
$this->q = "SELECT * 
              FROM sh_item si
                      INNER JOIN sh_paramvalues sp
                            ON si.id = sp.itemid
             WHERE (si.title LIKE '%".$get[0]."%' 
                OR si.descr LIKE '%".$get[0]."%' 
                OR sp.value LIKE '%".$get[0]."%')
               AND sp.paramid = 3
             LIMIT '".$this->page->start."','".$this->page->on1page."'";
```

Comment: did't work.. and how i can get not all values sp.itemid but only where  paramid = 3 (for exampl) {General error: 1 no such column: sp.sh_paramvalues}

Comment: Sorry I've take the table name as a column from your post. My bad. The real column name is `value` I will edit it. And will add the paramid request from your comment.